# Uploading my database.sql file to Linux server using WinSCP

Tags: linux, winscp

I am having some bad issues on uploading a dumped database file from my local computer to server using WinSCP. On my local computer it is `abc.sql` and when it is uploaded it shows me `abc.sql.filepart`. What does it mean?

Thanks in advance for the responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your upload is not finished or was aborted. Many client use this suffix as a temporary file during a running upload.

Comment: Cool thanks. I solved it by archive then transfer. :-)
Thanks